# Convert C# SQL Loop to Linq

Tags: c#, sql, performance, linq

I have a list Called ListTypes that holds 10 types of products. Below the store procedure loops and gets every record with the product that is looping and it stores it in the list ListIds. This is killing my sql box since I have over 200 users executing this constantly all day.

I know is not a good architecture to loop a sql statement, but this the only way I made it work. Any ideas how I can make this without looping? Maybe a Linq statement, I never used Linq with this magnitude. Thank you.

```
protected void GetIds(string Type, string Sub)
{
   LinkedIds.Clear();

  using (SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(connstr))
  {
    for (int x = 0; x < ListTypes.Count; x++)
    {
        cs.Open();
        SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("spUI_LinkedIds", cs);
        select.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", Type);
        select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sub", Sub);
        select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransId", ListTypes[x]);

        SqlDataReader dr = select.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            ListIds.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr["LinkedId"]));
        }
        cs.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it always 10 items in the list?

Comment: @DavidG is dynamic so it could be 10, 15 or 8.

Comment: why dont you have this in a dataset and assign the dataset object to a **var** object?? or you can go ahead with datareader as well and assign the datareader object to **var** object `var dr= select.ExecuteReader();`

Comment: One slight optimization: create the SqlCommand and it's parameters *once*, outside of the loop. Then inside the loop set the values of those params & execute. Leave the connection open for the entire loop.

Comment: @Neel Why do you want to add me in LinkedIn?!

Comment: Is the Stored Procedure capable of receiving more than one set of parameters at once? I mean, it isn't technically the loop that's causing problems, it's the repeated calls to the DB. Do you want to move the process performed by the Stored Procedure into the code?

Comment: @Neel That's what StackOverflow is for!

Comment: Put ListTypes in a datatable and pass (once) to an sp expecting a table variable? (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/214492/Passing-a-datatable-to-a-stored-procedure-in-Sql-S)

Comment: @GuyPassy yes. The constant looping of the sql query is causing my sql % processing time to go high. I would like to do it in Linq but I have no Idea.

Comment: @Apollo Well, as you haven't shown us anything regarding the process performed by the Stored Procedure - there's not much to do with Linq... best you can do is what JoelCoehoorn posted as an answer. Otherwise, you would need to either try moving the actual business logic out of the Stored Procedure and into the code

Comment: The idea is lets say I have a table and I have to get all records from the table that has this 10 types of products. How can I get all of this products? But this number is dynamic.

Comment: @Appollo if `GetIds` is confined to `spUI_linkedIds`, then the best you will get are modest variations of the same iterative process. If you want to optimize 'GetIds', consider reworking this function so that it works directly with the tables from code using ORM.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, but this wouldn't fit in a comment. You can at least update your existing code to be more efficient like this:

```
protected List<int> GetIds(string Type, string Sub, IEnumerable<int> types)
{
    var result = new List<int>();

    using (SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(connstr))
    using (SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("spUI_LinkedIds", cs))
    {
        select.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //Don't use AddWithValue! Be explicit about your DB types
        // I had to guess here. Replace with the actual types from your database
        select.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDBType.VarChar, 10).Value = Type;
        select.Parameters.Add("@Sub", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = Sub;
        var TransID = select.Parameters.Add("@TransId", SqlDbType.Int);
        cs.Open();

        foreach(int type in types)
        {
            TransID.Value = type;
            SqlDataReader dr = select.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                result.Add((int)dr["LinkedId"]);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that this way you only open and close the connection once. Normally in ADO.Net it's better to use a new connection and re-open it for each query. The exception is in a tight loop like this. Also, the only thing that changes inside the loop this way is the one parameter value. Finally, it's better to design methods that don't rely on other class state. This method no longer needs to know about the `ListTypes` and `ListIds` class variables, which makes it possible to (among other things) do better unit testing on the method.

Again, this isn't a full answer; it's just an incremental improvement. What you really need to do is write another stored procedure that accepts a table valued parameter, and build on the query from your existing stored procedure to JOIN with the table valued parameter, so that all of this will fit into a single SQL statement. But until you share your stored procedure code, this is about as much help as I can give you.

Comment: var TransID = select.Parameters.Add("@TransId", SqlDbType.Int); This has to go thru the list ListTypes, the number always changes.

Comment: The idea is lets say I have a table and I have to get all records from the table that has this 10 types of products. How can I get all of this products? But this number is dynamic.

Comment: @Apollo You would pass the list types as an argument, and if you keep reading this code will assign a value to the parameter inside the loop from the argument on each iteration,

Comment: Are you sure that closing and opening a connection is a problem? I believe connection pool takes care of it.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Normally, it does. But in a tight loop, this can be much more efficient.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn where does the 10 come from? "@Sub", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10) I never wrote code like this in C#.

Comment: It's a guess at the length of the DB type. Replace it with the actual size of that parameter in your stored procedure. Don't ever use the AddWithValue() function.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn why is not a good idea to use AddWithValue()? Just want to learn

Comment: It forces .Net to _guess_ the parameter type, and sometimes .Net will guess wrong. Often it doesn't matter: even if the parameter type is wrong, Sql Server will just do a type conversion and go on it's merry way. But every now and then Sql Server won't be able to make that conversion on the parameter itself, and instead have to do per-row conversions for the values in your table, or be unable to use an index, and that can have drastic performance implications.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the improvements others wrote.
You could insert your ID's into a temp table and then make one

```
SELECT * from WhatEverTable WHERE transid in (select transid from #tempTable)
```

On a MSSQL this works really fast.

When you're not using a MSSQL it could be possible that one great SQL-Select with joins is faster than a SELECT IN. You  have to test these cases by your own on your DBMS.

Answer (score -1):

According to your comment:
`The idea is lets say I have a table and I have to get all records from the table that has this 10 types of products. How can I get all of this products? But this number is dynamic.`

So... why use a stored procedure at all? Why not query the table?

```
//If [Type] and [Sub] arguments are external inputs - as in, they come from a user request or something - they should be sanitized. (remove or escape '\' and apostrophe signs)
//create connection

string queryTmpl = "SELECT LinkedId FROM [yourTable] WHERE [TYPE] = '{0}' AND [SUB] = '{1}' AND [TRANSID] IN ({2})";
string query = string.Format(queryTmpl, Type, Sub, string.Join(", ", ListTypes);
SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand(query, cs);

//and so forth
```

To use Linq-to-SQL you would need to map the table to a class. This would make the query simpler to perform.

Comment: Yes, let says I want to get all records that are cars, bikes, wheels, etc. This could be dynamic and I need to add them to a list. I dont want to loop one by one and stored them into a list.

Comment: @Apollo This doesn't loop. This simply goes to "yourTable" and returns all of the records in which the "WHERE" clause is true. Each user would then only make one request to the DB instead of `ListTypes.length` number of times